# Unable to set array property in angular6

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6

I need to set array property in angular 6 with this code :

```
this.addupdate.roleids=this.selectedRole;
```

but it shows me this error :

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'roleids' of undefined
>       at AccessLevelComponent.push../src/app/admin/admin/dashboard/role/access-level/access-level.component.ts.AccessLevelComponent.AddRoleClaim (access-level.component.ts:60)

```
selectedRole:string[]=['1011','1010','1005'];
```

and my interface :

```
export interface IAddorupdateRole {
  roleids:string[];
  roleid:number;
}
```

this my code :

```
public AddRoleClaim(){
  console.log("enter AddRoleClaim.Ts");
  this.addupdate.roleids=this.selectedRole;
  this.addupdate.roleid=this.roleId;
  this.roleService.AddOrUpdateRoleCalim(this.addupdate).subscribe((data)=>
    {
      console.log("seccess" + data);
    }
  );
}
```

What's the problem ? how can I solve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`roleids` is to be accessed on `this.addupdate` but apparently `this.addupdate` is undefined. Maybe it hasn't been initialized yet.

Try to initialize `this.addupdate` to a basic object in the `ngOnInit` something like this:

```
addupdate: IAddorupdateRole;

ngOnInit() {
  this.addupdate = {
    roleids = [],
    roleid = 0
  }
}
```

---

Here's a [**Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dcbebp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) for your ref.